# Navigating through MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got 4 screen. X,A,B,C. The navigation pattern should be as follow

[image]

Here is code

X Screen

```
class X extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('Navigate to A'),
        onPressed: () {
          A.show(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A screen

```
class A extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => A(), fullscreenDialog: false),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('Navigate to B'),
          onPressed: () {
            B.show(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

B class

```
class B extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => B(), fullscreenDialog: false),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('Navigate to C'),
          onPressed: () {
            C.show(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

C class

```
class C extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => C(), fullscreenDialog: false),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('Navigate back to A'),
          onPressed: () {
            A.show(context); //<=== here is problem
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Problem I've got is when I navigate from screen C back to screen A and press back button on app bar then it get me back to screen C. I need to be able to navigate back from C to B, B to A, and A to X but once I navigate from C to A I need to navigate back to X or again to B on pressing the button

**UPDATE**

I guess I kinda managed that with try and fail technique and honestly I don't understand why does it work as I want. Please if you know why this works and have an explanation then please provide an answer. Here is what I did

I've added new static function in Screen A

```
  static Future<void> back(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => A(),
            fullscreenDialog: false),
        ModalRoute.withName('/'));
  }
```

and call it in my screen C in my button

```
A.back(context)
```

Comment: Use `pushNamedReplacement` at B to C

Comment: @dev-aentgs and BTW I'm not using named route

Comment: @dev-aentgs please see update in my question... any idea?

Comment: @dev-aentgs already gave you easiest way - just `pushReplacement()`

Comment: @SergeySalnikov pushReplacement get me to screen A from screen C but by pressing back in app bar back button it get me to screen B instead of Screen X as I mentioned in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code

1. give a name to A page route
2. on C page do popUntil on button

```
class A extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => A(),
          settings: RouteSettings(name: 'A'), // <-- change 1 give a name
          fullscreenDialog: false),
    );
  }
...
```

```
class C extends StatelessWidget {
...  
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.settings.name == 'A'); //<=== will pop until A change 2
...
```

[see it works in dartpad](https://dartpad.cn/7dea8ef70e9a7b21f726ed055daad44b)

[working gist used in dartpad](https://gist.github.com/cutzmf/7dea8ef70e9a7b21f726ed055daad44b)

Whats going on in your Update `A.back`?

1. It's pushing **new** route with page A (old will be destroyed)
2. And removes all routes till first route for now it X
3. But if before X is more routes will remove them too

Drawback - on iOS `swipe back` behavior invoking `Navigator.pop` and there is no straight way to call your `A.back` in this case

```
  static Future<void> back(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => A(),
            fullscreenDialog: false),
        ModalRoute.withName('/'));
  }
```

Comment: There is a little problem... Please see the diagram in the question.. With your approach if you get to screen `c` and press back button it get you to screen `a` which is not what I wanted. I need to be able to get back from screen `c` into screen `b` but when I navigate from screen `c` to screen `a` then on pressing back button it get me to screen `x`.

Comment: ahh... I see - I'll update my answer soon. Review your diagram - there is no way from `C->B`

Comment: I've updated gist check behavior https://gist.github.com/cutzmf/7dea8ef70e9a7b21f726ed055daad44b

If it's what you want - I'll update answer for you

Comment: I've already done that just reopen  https://dartpad.cn/7dea8ef70e9a7b21f726ed055daad44b

Comment: Yes... that is exactly wha I needed... so you have used `popUntil` instead... please update you answer if you can. so what are the differences between my solution and yours then?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Your solution creates **new** A page, mine just poping all routes till A and keep it (**old**) in stack without recreation page A

Comment: Ahh.. I see.. well to be honest that behaviour is actually in my case extra bonus because it also updates the screen which is great. But definitely your solution is better.. Thanks man...

Comment: in case to recreate A - change on page C button to call `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, <A route>, (route) => route.isFirst);`

Comment: I mean that if you really want to recreate A - you can use my answer with this modification - it will recreate A

Answer (score 1):

```
  class C extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {
         await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => C(), fullscreenDialog: false),  
   );
   }

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
     body: Center(
     child: FlatButton(
      child: Text('Navigate back to A'),
      onPressed: () {
        int count = 0;
             Navigator.of(context).popUntil((_) => count++ >= 2);
      },
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}
```