# Flutter/Dart - Navigator.pop(context) - How to Pop two Contexts back?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, materialpageroute

I've got;

- screen/widget `Home()` which calls;
- screen/widget `MainStage()` which calls;
- future method `futureStage()` which builds;
- PageViewBuilder `StageBuilder()` which contains;

`SwipeGestureRecognizer` which calls;

```
Navigator.push (context,
                  PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.downToUp,
                    child: HomeReply(),
                  ));
```

- `HomeReply()` contains;
- `appBar` with an arrow/button that allows the user to;
- `Navigator.pop(context)`;

How do I get the Navigator to pop back to `Home()`?

Comment: `Navigator.popUntil(context,ModalRoute.withName('/'));`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733327/13625305) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out HomeReply() had an extra MaterialApp in the build. Once I removed this it all worked as normal with `Navigator.pop(context);`.

Answer (score 1):

The navigator is a stack so you can use the [`popUntil`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html) method to pop back to your home() screen.

```dart
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'));
```

or

```dart
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == "Home");
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw your comment while writing my answer. Will delete it.

Comment: I'm guessing that didn't work because I didn't use a named route in the first place. I've been using a BottomNavigationBar in Home() and it seemed easier to just call Navigator.push (context,
                  PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.downToUp,
                    child: HomeReply(),
                  ));

Comment: So is there a way I can call Home()  with popUntil?

Comment: You can use route.settings.name. I personally did not try it without named parameters but I guess you can dehug a bit to see what routename is saved when you push home () and then use that?

Comment: I used this code to check my Home() route. var route = ModalRoute.of(context);
    if(route!=null){
      print(route.settings.name);
    } It gave me "/". So then I tried this; Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == "/"); But unfortunately it didn't work.